# Rails Nginx - 404 Not Found - Error for /public folder content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

After been in Heroku for some time, I am moving to DigitalOcean to host my blog. But I have been troubled by receiving 404s for folder `/public` and `/fonts`.

I believe this is because of an Nginx config issue. I have attached the `conf` file belog.

I am a newby to this stuff. I was wondering to copy the /assets seciton for each 404 dir. But that doesn't sound sense to me.

I would be glad if some one could point out the error and give suggestions.

```
upstream guruof.it {
  server unix:///var/run/guruofit.sock;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name guruof.it; # change to match your URL
  root /var/www/guruof.it/public; # I assume your app is located at that location

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://guruof.it; # match the name of upstream directive which is defined above
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }

  location @guruof.it {
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://guruof.it;
  }

  location ~* ^/assets/ {
    # Per RFC2616 - 1 year maximum expiry
    expires 1y;
    add_header Cache-Control public;

    # Some browsers still send conditional-GET requests if there's a
    # Last-Modified header or an ETag header even if they haven't
    # reached the expiry date sent in the Expires header.
    add_header Last-Modified "";
    add_header ETag "";
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Wired enaugh I am getting a forbidden 403 error for the site today after I restarted the VPS.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using capistrano to deploy then you need to add 'current' to the root path

something like this

root /var/www/guruof.it/current/public;

That should work.